# how to give all p-elements a class name?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to give all of my p-elements a class name, can't seem to figure out what the problem is here.

```
var para = document.getElementsByTag("p");
para.className += "myClass";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to loop over the collection and assign (it's also `document.getElementsByTagName("p");`)

```
for (var i = 0; i < para.length; i++) {
    para[i].className += " myClass";
    //                   ^^^
    //As @nnnnnn pointed out - a space beforehand will ensure the class is added to existing classes - and not added as a single word.
}
```

Comment: If you're using += you should include a space before the name.

Comment: @Alex - because using += implies you want to add the class in addition to any existing classes, so you need a space to separate the class names. If you want to *replace* any existing classes then use = rather than +=.

Comment: @nnnnnn It makes sense now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in `getElementsByTag`, should be `getElementsByTagName`.

Also `para` is an array of elements, not a single one. So you need to iterate against it and set className on each element, like this:

```
var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(var i=0; i<para.length; i++){
    para[i].className += " myClass";
}
```

Comment: Not an array, a [*NodeList*](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177).

Comment: Right :), but NodeList behaves just like an array would.

Comment: Only in that they have a self–adjusting *length* and their members can be accessed by index. They aren't instances of Array, don't have their helpful methods and are host objects, not built–in. ;-)